# Error: fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'nb_epoch'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, data-science

```
classifier.add(Dense(6, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim = 11))
classifier.add(Dense(6,kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'sigmoid')) 

classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', 
                metrics = ['accuracy']) 

#classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 10, epochs = 100)

classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 10, nb_epoch = 100)
```

if I run this, it says:

```
fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'nb_epoch'
```

I tried `nb_epochs` as well as `epoch`. Still it gives error. I tried epochs and it gave a new error saying :

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 11 but received input with shape (None, 1)
```

What I'm coding is an artificial neural network code to predict price. I would be thankful if u could help me out.

Comment: It is neither `np_epoch` nor `epoch`, it is `epochs`. Your second error is due to incompatible input shape. It expects input shape something like `(N,11)` but have passed some input which its last dimension is 1, instead of 11.

Comment: Thanks for replying, yes it is epochs! but how do i change from (None,1) to (None,11)?

Comment: ```classifier.add(Dense(6, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim = 11))
classifier.add(Dense(6,kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'sigmoid'))
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 10, epochs = 100)```

Comment: Your reply would be really appreciated! My Project deadline is nearing 2 weeks left. Thank you!

Comment: What is the shape of `X_train` and `y_train`?

Comment: ```from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
classifier = Sequential()```

Answer (score 7):

Use '`epochs`' insted of '`nb_epoch`'.